# Android Multiple Devices Best Practices

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I have several android applications in the market. Some users are reporting force closes on certain devices. The only device I test on/have access to is a Nexus One. I also test my applications on many different permutations of the simulator.

Does anyone have any advice on how to ensure device compatibility? Or anything in general to avoid issues like this? Currently I am getting complaints from Samsung Moment and Motorla Cliq users, but I am not about to go out and buy these devices. I have looked up these devices and tested the apps on the simulator with the same version of android, but they work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If they are layout issues you should create an emulator with a custom size.

If it's something that just can be reproduced in a particular device, you can try: http://www.perfectomobile.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can collect logs and error reports from users of those phones, to see what the issue is.  Without specifics of your app, its hard to say what to focus on.  Make sure you've covered everything in [what to test](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/what_to_test.html), and [supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).